# How to update listpreference summary (findPreference() does not work)?

Tags: java, android, listpreference

So, SettingsActivity implements a SettingsFragment. I am following Udacity course. My main problem is, findPreference() does not work! 
Here's what it says on developer.android.com site:

findPreference
Added in API level 1
Preference findPreference (CharSequence key)
This method was deprecated in API level 11.
This function is not relevant for a modern fragment-based PreferenceActivity.

**So, how do I bring in listPreference for a FRAGMENT?** If I use PreferenceActivity, then this method works but it is deprecated.

```
package com.example.android.listview1;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.preference.*;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow;

import java.util.prefs.PreferenceChangeListener;



public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements     Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,new SettingsFragment()).commit();

    **bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference());**


}
private void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference)
{
 preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
onPreferenceChange(preference,PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext()).getString(preference.getKey(),"") );
}

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object     newValue)    {

  String value = newValue.toString();

    //if the preference is an instance of ListPreference then you convert the preference object to ListPreference

    if(preference instanceof ListPreference) {
        ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
        //return the index of the value that is selected
        int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(value);

        //if there's at least 1 item in the ListPreference, then you set the summary by getting the object at the index

        if (prefIndex >= 0) {
            preference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
        }

        else
            preference.setSummary(value);
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve the issue. Move all the code/methods except for onCreate to SettingsFragment. Move bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference()) to SettingsFragment as well and get rid of the implementation from onCreate().